# Set Constraints for ViewController presented

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, constraints

I am pushing a ViewController over my current ViewController.

The ViewController I want to push is a WebView, but I guess that does not matter.

[image: Screenshot of the pushed ViewController]

I want the presented ViewController not to go under the status bar. But how can I set these constraints?

This is my code to load the pushed ViewController:

```
@objc func loadWebView(sender: UIButton) {

        let vc = WebViewVC()

        webViewVC = vc

        self.present(webViewVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

if I set constraints for webViewVC.view in relation to the view of the parent ViewController it of course tells me that it is not allowed because the views are in different view hierarchies.

This is how I set up my layout in the WebViewVC:

```
func setUpView() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view
        view.st(navigationBar,webView)

        navigationBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true
        navigationBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: you cannot put that over the status bar. Either you can remove status bar completely from this view or from entire app(there are lot of internet resources on how to do this) or create the second VC accordingly.

Comment: You are putting it over status bar. It is better to create the second View Controller by keeping the status bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple doc:

> The layout guide representing the portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content.

Change your navigation bar top anchor with:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
     let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
     navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true

} else {
     navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

where the view is your **self.view**  not the new view created (view = UIView() )